# Error 400 using an API with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, http, post

I am using an API to create PDF from a json.

I am using `$http`angularjs service, when I make request I get a HTTP 400 error code.

This is the code.

```
angular.module('instantPDFApp', [])
.controller('mainController', ['$http', function ($http){
    $http.post("https://yogthos.p.mashape.com/", '[{}, ["paragraph", "some text"]]' ,{
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'X-Mashape-Key' : 'MXQJRkqiLumshE4GCKbhIvtR3ytvp19hpZxjsn2vSk4L5dXrE4'
        }
    }).then(
        function (response) {
            document.write(response.data);
        },

        function () {
            console.error("Error");
        }
    );
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is server response (Bad request). Try to use full request in angular.
For example:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/someUrl',
    params: {
        param1: 'hello'
    },
    headers: {
       'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
   // this callback will be called asynchronously
   // when the response is available
 }, function errorCallback(response) {
   // called asynchronously if an error occurs
   // or server returns response with an error status.
 });
```

Full list of request data you can find here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Hope it will help you.